# Highcharts Map not rendering no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am attempting to take the example produced by Highcharts here http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/color-axis and substitute the data loaded by the $.getJson with a local JSON file called 'testdata1.json'.

The code I've modified below produces no errors yet the map does not render. I think it's because the testdata1.json is loaded late, after the javascript is executed. If so, is there a better way I should be doing this -- perhaps waiting for the data to load before executing the JS file? I attempted to do this by placing a

```
$(document).ready(
```

in front of the function but it didn't work. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated, I think it's something relatively minor that is just escaping me.

Thank you.

```
$(function () {

        // Map options
        var options = {

            chart : {
                renderTo: '#map',
                borderWidth : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'US population density (/km²)'
            },

            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
                floating: true,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 1,
                type: 'logarithmic',
                minColor: '#EEEEFF',
                maxColor: '#000022',
                stops: [
                    [0, '#EFEFFF'],
                    [0.67, '#4444FF'],
                    [1, '#000022']
                ]
            },

            series : [{
                animation: {
                    duration: 1000
                },
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
                joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: 'white',
                    format: '{point.code}'
                },
                name: 'Population density',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.value}/km²'
                }
            }]
        };


    $.getJSON('static/data/testdata1.json', function (data) {

        // Make codes uppercase to match the map data
        $.each(data, function () {
            this.code = this.code.toUpperCase();
        });
        options.series.data= data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options)

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems. Here's a fiddle based on their sample that uses your approach, but still uses their data, and works: http://jsfiddle.net/g29k24vw/1/

Here are the important parts:

```
chart : {
    renderTo: 'container',
    borderWidth : 1,
    type: 'map'
},
```

And:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=us-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    // Make codes uppercase to match the map data
    $.each(data, function () {
        this.code = this.code.toUpperCase();
    });
    options.series[0].data= data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Note the differences here:

- You need to specify the chart type in options if you're going to instantiate the chart object directly instead of using the jQuery helper.
- `renderTo` doesn't want a hash in front of the element name.
- `options.series[0].data`, not `options.series.data`...`series` is actually an array of objects.

Comment: I would add one more thing: loading local JSON file - it will cause an error in JS console (CORS).

Comment: Thank you for this answer @S-McCrohan but it didn't work initially. Another problem was that the callback was not firing because my json file wasn't valid. So to everyone reading this from the future if your Highcharts or other callback isn't firing, make sure you have valid JSON!

Comment: Whoops! Good catch. In fact, see the 'Important' block in the middle of this page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/